# Pull, virtualize, and bash into a docker image

Tags: docker

I have [a docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/verdverm/pypge-eval/) I'd like to poke inside. How can I pull it and get access to a shell on it? I tried `sudo docker exec -it verdverm/pypge-experiments bash`, but it just gave me `Error response from daemon: No such container: verdverm/pypge-experiments`. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace exec with run:

```
sudo docker run -it verdverm/pypge-experiments bash
```

Comment: [`exec`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/exec/) is to run a command in a running container.